# Verifying an inequality

Tags: inequalities

I want to verify an inequality in mathematica but I don't know where I'm mistaken. Please help me out, thanks in advance.

$\psi(t):\to[0,\infty)$ and $\phi(t):\to[0,\infty)$

where;

$\psi(t)=3/2*t^2$ and  $\phi(t)=t$

$d(x,y)=|x-y|$ where $x,y \epsilon \mathbb{R}$

The above are the conditions which I want to put on the given inequality

\begin{equation}3*t^2*d(x,y)-3/2*t^2*d(x,y)]\leq(3/2*t^2*d(x,y))^\alpha*(t*d(x,y))^{1-\alpha} \end{equation}
where $\alpha \epsilon(0,1)$

I have tried the code below:

```
-Infinity < x < Infinity;

-Infinity < y < Infinity;

0 <= t < Infinity;

0 < alpha < 1;

d(x,y) = Abs[x-y];

3*t^2*d(x,y)-3/2*t^2*d(x,y) <= (3/2*t^2*d(x,y))^alpha*(t*d(x,y))^1-alpha
```

Furthermore, I have also tried it with Reduce[ ]

Comment: What did you try with `Reduce[]`?

Comment: No, I just simply wrote the inequality and the conditions

Comment: Hi WKhan, welcome to Mathematica.SE! This site is about questions regarding the software Mathematica. In case you are trying to solve your inequality with Mathematica it's always good to update your question and show the code you already tried and what your specific question is. If you have a general math question math.stackexchange.com is the place for that, in that case your question should be migrated.

Comment: The assumptions should be written as `assume = Element[{x, y}, Reals] && t >= 0 && 0 < alpha < 1;` The definition for `d` should be `d[x_,y_] = Abs[x-y]`. The inequality should be written `ineq = 3*t^2*d[x, y] - 
   3/2*t^2*d[x, y] <= (3/2*t^2*d[x, y])^alpha*(t*d[x, y])^(1 - alpha)`. Unfortunately, `Reduce[ineq && assume]` does not work even with the corrections.

Comment: Thank you for you time, I tried your given code and yeah it doesn't work with Reduce and even with Refine

Comment: `Simplify[ineq,assume]` returns `t*(3*2^alpha*t-2*3^alpha*t^alpha)*Abs[x-y]<=0` Can you see any additional hints to add to `assume` to enable it to further `Simplify` this, perhaps even to `True`?

Comment: It is able to `Simplify[3*2^alpha*t - 2*3^alpha*t^alpha<= 0,assume]` to `True` so it is the two extra factors that it is uncertain about.

Comment: I can't see any additional hints to add to `assume`

Comment: I just want to verify the inequality generally